Graduate Instance colour by constant interpolation
I'm trying to graduate between two instance colours. Red at the bottom and blue at the top.
I can achieve a hard divide, and I can get a smooth colour graduation between the two, but I want a graduation that mixes blue balls and red without any purple appearing.
Desired outcome: 
Thanks for looking!


Well, that's how color works. Maybe you can show an example created in some image editing software like Photoshop for example, how exactly a gradient between blue and red should look like without purple? As it stands, this is not a problem in Blender, this is more about color theory.

jpg added to illustrate concept.

Oh, you want to mix the spheres, I see... well, this is not what I understood from "a smooth colour graduation". Mixing them is of course no problem, sorry I focused too much on that "graduation".

Add noise to your gradient (z position) and then use a greater/less than node to split the gradient into 0 and 1.
By increasing the amplitude of the noise (see the multiply node in the screenshot) you can adjust the length of the transition.


Fantastic. Works perfectly! Thank you Leander, that is exactly what I was after.
